# Puppet get username from Configuration file using puppet

Tags: linux, server, puppet, rpmbuild

I need to build a RPM for a set of libraries, but the problem is I can compile and build it in Dev server and need to deploy in all QA, PROD and test servers which has different user names, so I need to build my rpm to contain and pick username for respective servers during installation, can someone help me with this. How to do this using puppet..? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done cleanly with stock RPMs.

As a hack, you can have a `%post` script `chown` all the files after detecting which username to use, but that's going to cause errors later when you do things like try to verify the RPM installation.

I'd recommend (a) having a new username that you use for the RPM/service across all servers or (b) building separate RPMs for each target environment.